# How does telegram download files in browser?

Tags: html, telegram, web-storage

I would like to understand what html5 feature does telegram web uses to download shared files in browser before giving me a prompt to download it on my hard disk? I thought it was web-storage but there is a limit of 10mb and I have seen telegram download files in Gbs.

Answer (score -1):

The standard way of downloading files on client-side is by using the  tag.

```
<a href="/example.jpg" download>
```

See more here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

They could be using this [function](http://danml.com/download.html) for downloading instead.

Comment: I know how to download a file but telegram can download it in background(just like mega app) and after background download finishes it triggers download to your hardisk(i.e you see a download box which instantly finishes.)